# Recognizing type of descriptor in Linux

Tags: linux, file-descriptor

I know that process with `pid = 1475` has opened two descriptors: 3 and 475.
How to learn more about these descriptors (like what is a type of descriptor and so on).

Answer (score 1):

`stat()`ing `/proc/1475/fd/3` and `/proc/1475/fd/475` will provide a little bit of info.

For more, I think you'll need to ask the process or attach a debugger to it `gdb -p 1475` (privileges likely needed)  and force it to give you your answers.

Comment: I attached but I don't know how to extract that information.